# I am trying to make a jump with this fps controller. Everything I've tried so far doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Tags: c#

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = (int)12f;

    public float gravity = (int)-9.81;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = (int)0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    Vector3 Velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    public float jumpHieght = (int)3f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if (isGrounded && Velocity.y < 0) ;
        {
            Velocity.y = -4f;
        }
    
        
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) ;
    
            Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHieght * -2f * gravity);
        }
    
      
        Velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    
        controller.Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    
        
    }

}
```

You might notice this as Brackey's fps code with some tweaks (because it is) but his jump code didn't work. What happens is the capsule continues to rise.

Comment: There are a few other issues with your code, like casting floats with `(int)` which yields meaningless results. I updated my answer. Maybe you'll get to read this comment before someone deletes it for no sane reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (isGrounded && Velocity.y < 0) ;
    {
        Velocity.y = -4f;
    }
```

`if` does not require a semicolon. Do this instead ( for *all* of your `if`s):

```
    if (isGrounded && Velocity.y < 0)
    {
        Velocity.y = -4f;
    }
```

The long version:
`if` says: if some condition is true, execute the next statement or block. Since you're putting the `;` right after the closing `)` in the `if`, the "next statement" is empty, so your `if` doesn't do anything.

Also, things like this:

```
public float groundDistance = (int)0.4f;
```

This takes the floating point value `0.4`, casts it to an int (which equals `0`), and assigns that to `groundDistance`. So, your `groundDistance` value is always 0.  The line should be:

```
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
```

... and you've done that in several places as well.